# How to scrape the images from this javascript website?

Tags: python, scripting, web-crawler

[link text](http://www.jingjilei.cn/n/drspath.shtml?kid=656667676A6B686A3135373334313034&username=80F6485A99802CFF790EEA7BD76F2145&spagenum=201&pages=50&fid=5122699&a=3B8B8EC0615479C3452F9B8605C315B7&btime=2010-12-09&etime=2010-12-29&template=bookdsr1&firstdrs=/bookDetail.jsp%3FdxNumber%3D000006801452%26d%3D41DAB34EF8738CF38EAB3D946D804634)

This is a link from a digital book library.There are forward and backward buttons to see next and previous page.I want to download these pictures automatically. I have once used urllib in python but the website baned it soon. I just want to download this book for study purpose so can anyone recommend me some programming tools such as web-spiders which can simulate the process of turning pages and get the pictures automatically. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That site uses Javascript, so you can't easily scrape it with Python. Two suggestions:

1. Work out what requests are being made when clicking the next button. You can do this with a tool like firebug. You might then find you can scrape it without processing any JS.
2. Use a tool such as [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) which allows for browser scripting which lets you "execute" the JS.

As for the site blocking you, there are two ways to reduce the chance of being blocked:

1. Change your user-agent to that of a common browser, e.g. Firefox.
2. Add random delays between accessing the next image, so that you appear more human-like.

Answer (score 0):

wget is an excellent web spider

http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget

Answer (score 0):

You need a real browser to work with this (kind of) site. Selenium is one option, but it is more geared towards web testing. For web scraping iMacros is really nice. I had a quick test and it works well with iMacros for Firefox/IE.

Chris